# XPATH Error : Unable to evaluate expression

Tags: xpath

I have an xml like this as mentioned below. I am trying to obtain value for Cardnumber using following expression.

XPATH :

```
paymentService/ns0:submit/ns0:order/ns0:paymentDetails/ns0:VISA-SSL/cardNumber
```

But it's giving me error. Can any1 guide me on this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paymentService version="1.0">
    <ns0:submit xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/Payment/PaymentProcessors/WorldPay_CC/SharedResources/Schemas/paymentService_v1.dtd">
        <ns0:order>
            <description>description</description>
            <amount value="500" currencyCode="EUR" exponent="2"/>
            <ns0:paymentDetails>
                <ns0:VISA-SSL>
                    <cardNumber>00009875083428500</cardNumber>
                    <expiryDate>
                        <date month="02" year="2008"/>
                    </expiryDate>
                    <cardHolderName>test</cardHolderName>
                </ns0:VISA-SSL>
                <session shopperIPAddress="192.165.22.35" id=""/>
            </ns0:paymentDetails>
            <shopper>
                <browser>
                    <acceptHeader>text/html</acceptHeader>
                    <userAgentHeader>mozilla 5.0</userAgentHeader>
                </browser>
            </shopper>
        </ns0:order>
    </ns0:submit>
</paymentService>
```

Thanks

Comment: If it "gives an error", then tell us what the error is! The message might make no sense to you, but there's a good chance someone here can explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Your `xmlns:ns0` is misplaced, and (think of this way) because `ns0` is defined **after** `<ns0:submit>` tag, `ns0:submit` is "undefined" and thus the parse error.</del>

**Edit**:

If you need to use this XPath in PHP, you'll either have to declare the namespace before use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paymentService version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/Payment/PaymentProcessors/WorldPay_CC/SharedResources/Schemas/paymentService_v1.dtd">
    <ns0:submit>
```

Or register the namespace before evaluating your XPath (Thanks to @MiMo for pointing out):

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns0","http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/Payment/PaymentProcessors/WorldPay_CC/SharedResources/Schemas/paymentService_v1.dtd");
```

Also add a slash before your XPATH:

```
/paymentService/ns0:submit/ns0:order/ns0:paymentDetails/ns0:VISA-SSL/cardNumber
```

[Live demo with declaration first](http://3v4l.org/XSerU) or [Live demo with namespace registration](http://3v4l.org/JtKca) (both are demonstrated in PHP).

Comment: Defining a namespace within the first element that uses it is legal in XML - the XML in the OP is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the node

```
<paymentService version="1.0">
```

Since this is not ended you have to comment it or end it properly.
If you comment that try out with this XPATH

```
/ns0:submit/ns0:order/ns0:paymentDetails/ns0:VISA-SSL/cardNumber
```

Comment: It's a formatting problem; OP didn't indent his code properly, so SO "hides" the closing `</paymentService>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the namespace before evaluating the XPath:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns0', 'http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/Payment/PaymentProcessors/WorldPay_CC/SharedResources/Schemas/paymentService_v1.dtd');
```

where `$xml` is a `SimpleXMLElement` variable containing your XML.

Your XPath needs to start with `/` as per Passerby answer:

```
/paymentService/ns0:submit/ns0:order/ns0:paymentDetails/ns0:VISA-SSL/cardNumber
```

Comment: The second part of the answer is wrong. If the context item for the XPath expression is the document (root) node, then the leading "/" is redundant.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I agree, but I tried without the slash and  it does not work. The context does not appear to be the document root - the PHP XML library seems a bit quirky. Also the namespace handling is strange: usually you have to pass namespaces separately to use them in an XPath, but with the PHP library IF the namespace is declared in the root element it can be used in the XPath

Comment: @MichaelKay Not true on _some_ implementation: http://3v4l.org/RZIQR http://3v4l.org/JtKca